# Nothing happens when i press the upload button in Uploadifive

Tags: php, codeigniter, uploadify

I was trying to implement the non-flash version of uploadifive. The demo that came with the download works fine. But, if i place the file within a view folder and call it from a controller it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my **view.php** file. It is placed in the view folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>UploadiFive Test</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.uploadifive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/uploadifive.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
.uploadifive-button {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#queue {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    height: 177px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 3px 3px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>UploadiFive Demo</h1>
    <form>
        <div id="queue"></div>
        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
        <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $timestamp = time();?>
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
                'auto'             : false,
                'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
                'formData'         : {
                                       'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                                       'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                                     },
                'queueID'          : 'queue',
                'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
                'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the **controller**:

```
<?php

class Upload_control extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();


    }

    function index()
    {


            $this->load->view('view.php');

    }
}
```

Ive placed the js scripts in js/ folder and css in css/ folder in the root of the website. I've placed the check-exists.php and uploadifive.php in the root of the website. I'm not sure if its even loading these scripts since the upload button looks different from the one in the demo. What am i doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: *sidenote:* Content Type header meta of HTML5 should be `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `developer console` for any error. Secondly change and write:

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.uploadifive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/uploadifive.css">
```

Comment: I added that, now it seems to work partially. I see the upload progress and when i press upload files it gives me a 404. Any ideas? EDIT: Is it because it can find my upload script?

Comment: The `check-exists.php` and `uploadifive.php` is not accessible by your ajax call.

Comment: In the line " 'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php', " I tried putting the absolute path like "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test_Website/application/views/" for the file. It didnt work.

Comment: I added the <?=base_url()?> before the check-exists.php and uploadifive.php. It did the trick. Thanks for your help. I accepted your answer. I wish i could upvote, but i dont have enough rep yet. Thanks again.

Comment: Happie to help :D @chris